# How can I show my own menu strip when Right-click in TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

As the Question, I want to show my own menuStrip when I Right-click in the Textbox and just in this textBox. You know that the default menu will appears,but I don't want that. How can I do that?

In other word: How to hide the default right-click menu in the TextBox?

Comment: You may mention the technology you use (Windows Forms, WPF, ...), and maybe also add another tag.

Comment: if you can; write it for both. but it is Windows Form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a contextMenuStrip control to the form, enter some menu items in the menu strip. Click the textbox and go to properties and in the properties select **ContextMenuStrip** and set the required contextMenuStrip control. Then the default context menu strip for the text box will not appear when you right click. See the following image.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is for WPF (XAML):

```
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Option 1"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Group">
                    <MenuItem Header="Option 2"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Option 3"></MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBox.ContextMenu>
    </TextBox>
```

So basically assign object of `ContextMenu` type to the `ContextMenu` property of the `TextBox`.

Answer (score 2):

This is for **Windows Forms**.

Add another `ContextMenuStrip` control to your form. Then, you set your `TextBox`'s `ContextMenuStrip` property to the new strip.