# How to override textbox context menu with parent control's context menu?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

I have a Panel with various child controls on it.  I assigned a context menu to the Panel and it comes up whether I right click on the Panel or on the controls... except for the TextBox control because it comes with its own built in context menu.

I would rather not have to set the context menu on controls directly because they are dynamically generated, and they are generated in a dll outside of the GUI that I'm using them on.  Is there any way I can force the Panel's context menu to come up instead of the TextBox's context menu without having to set the ContextMenuStrip property directly on the TextBox?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598318/how-can-i-show-my-own-menu-strip-when-right-click-in-textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a work-around for `without having to set the ContextMenuStrip property directly on the TextBox`:

Simply assign it.

```
textBox1.ContextMenuStrip = panel1.ContextMenuStrip;
```

or

```
textBox1.ContextMenuStrip = textBox1.Parent.ContextMenuStrip;
```

You can alternatively loop through the child controls of the panel and assign the menu strip to each child control.